# script not loading in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, underscores-wp

I am working on an underscores WordPress theme and I cannot seem to get any custom script to show results when I load the page. I have attempted to include a simple script 'test.js' in functions.php to test it out. All the other scripts work just fine. Any help would be appreciated:

```
function blake_eric_scripts() {

    /**
    * Enqeue bootstrap javascript
    */    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true);

    /**
    * Enqeue bootstrap styles
    */      
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 
'3.3.6', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'blake-eric-test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array('jquery'));

    /**
    * Enqeue styles.css
    */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blake-eric-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'blake-eric-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blake_eric_scripts' );
```

Here is the simple jQuery script "test.js":

```
$(function(){
  $('#main').addClass('test-class');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked **Console** tab under **Inspect Element**? Is there any error? Please post the error, if any.

Comment: There was an error that '$' is not a function, but it was solved after changing the code as specified below. Thank you, Mehul.

Answer (score 1):

replace your test.js with following set of codes :-

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#demo').addClass('test-class');
});
```

This types of error generally occurs because of conflict with others js files.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Anup

Answer (score 0):

By default Wordpress runs jQuery in no-conflict mode, so you can't use the $ sign and define a function like this

`$(function(){
  $('#main').addClass('test-class');
});`

Instead what you can do is

`jQuery(function($){
  $('#main').addClass('test-class');
});`

if you include the `$` sign inside the parenthesis you can use it on the rest of the function.
for more details check [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Thanks Biplav for the resource